# ApacheCamel - Know when streaming process finished?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a problem between version of dependencie `camel-spring-boot-dependencies` 3.10.0 and 3.11.0.

For this code :

> ```
>    from(quartz("quartz")
>             // Prevent concurrent calls
>             .stateful(true)
>             .cron("0/5 * * * * ?")
>             .autoStartScheduler(true)
>     ).id("quartz")
>             .autoStartup(true)
>             .startupOrder(1)
>
>             .process(utils::addElement)
>             .log("Quartz lance")
>             .to(direct("route_intermediaire"))
>             .delay(300000);
>
>     from(direct("route_stage")).id("route_stage").to(direct("route_test")).log("This
>     is the end");
>
>
>     from(direct("route_enrich_A"))
>             .id("route_enrich_A")
>             .delay(1000).syncDelayed()
>             .to(log("route_enrich_A"));
>
>
>     from(direct("route_enrich_B"))
>             .id("route_enrich_B")
>             .delay(1000).syncDelayed()
>             .to(log("route_enrich_B"));
>
>
>     from(direct("route_test"))
>             .id("route_test")
>             .split(body())
>             .streaming().parallelProcessing()
>             .threads(5)
>             .aggregate(AggregationStrategies.flexible().accumulateInCollection(ArrayList.class))
>             .constant(true)
>             .completionSize(2)
>             .completionInterval(1000)
>             .enrich(direct("route_enrich_A"))
>             .enrich(direct("route_enrich_B"))
>             .end();
> ```

> ```
>  public static void addElement(Exchange exchange) {
>
>     List<Integer> liste = new ArrayList<>();
>     for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++){
>         liste.add(i);
>     }
>
>     exchange.getIn().setBody(liste);
> }
> ```

The ouput with version 3.10.0 is :

```
c.e.demo.IndexeurAggregateBehavior       : Started IndexeurAggregateBehavior in 7.346 seconds (JVM running for 8.148)
quartz                                   : Quartz lance
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 1,5]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 6,7]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 0,2]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 8,9]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 4,3]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 0,2]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 1,5]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 6,7]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 4,3]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 8,9]
route_stage                              : This is the end
```

and for the version 3.11.0 is :

```
c.e.demo.IndexeurAggregateBehavior       : Started IndexeurAggregateBehavior in 5.455 seconds (JVM running for 6.141)
quartz                                   : Quartz lance
route_stage                              : This is the end
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 2,1]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 2,1]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 5,3]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 5,3]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 0,7]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 0,7]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 4,6]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 4,6]
route_enrich_A                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 8,9]
route_enrich_B                           : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: java.util.ArrayList, Body: 8,9]
```

With the version 3.11.0, the order of processing is not the same.
The problem for me is i want to know when the last item is finish. When the log message `This is the end` in version 3.10.0 is append.
I search in documentation, but i not found anything help me.

Thank for your help

Comment: If you need a deterministic order, disable the parallel processing. Even with 3.10.0, because of the parallelism, there is no guarantee you will have the exact same order in each run

Comment: The problem isn't a deterministic order, i want to know when the main route_stage is done.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options you can try:

- You could try to define the `This is the end` log statement or any code you want to perform once a route is considered done with an exchange as part of an [`.onCompletion()`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/oncompletion.html) DSL
- Write your own [route policy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/RoutePolicy.java) which you add to your route as explained in the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-policy.html#_using_route_policies_in_camel_routes). That policy acts on `onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange)` method invocations by Camel. You could also use a custom `RoutePolicyFactory` if you want to run that policy on every route
- You could also define a custom [EventNotifier](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/EventNotifier.java) implementation, i.e. through [EventNotifierSupport](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/EventNotifierSupport.java), and implement [`notify(CamelEvent event)`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/EventNotifier.java#L32) to act on [ExchangeCompletedEvent](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-base/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/event/ExchangeCompletedEvent.java)s. As this event notifier is added to Camel's `ManagementStrategy`, i.e. `camelContext.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(customEventNotifier)`, this basically fires for all completed exchanges then on each route therefore you'd probably need to filter for events triggered by the particular route you are interested in

I'd try from top to bottom as each of the mentioned approaches increases in complexity

Comment: Thank for your reply. I test "onCompletion", but not work. The "onCompletion" is launch before the end of process of "route_test".

Comment: I test also policy, same result, "onExchangeDone" is launch before the end of "route_test".

Comment: and the last solution with EventNotifier is too much in my opinion.

Comment: I find it odd that there isn't a simpler solution to my problem. Or perhaps my code is not a good practice for camel ?